# Simulating Time-Dependent Covariate and Applying coxph Function to Estimate Association Parameters

Tags: r, survival, simulation, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

Let $T$ denote a failure time random variable drawn from a proportional hazards model with a time-invariant covariate $X\sim U(2, 7)$ and a time-varying covariate $Z(t) = kt$ for $k > 0$. Assuming the baseline hazard function is Exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda = 1$, I can generate $200$ observations of right-censored failure time data with covariates from this model using the R code:

```
library(survival)   
# Set proportional hazards model parameters
gamma=c(0.15,0.05)
k = 5
# Generate failure/censoring times and covariate data
failure=c(); censor=c()
obs=c(); ind=c()
time_invariant=c(); time_variant=c()
  
## Survival Data Simulation
for (i in 1:200){
    temp.Z=runif(1, 2, 7)
    temp.U= runif(1,0,1)
    
    temp.T=(1/(gamma[2]*k))*log(1+(-(log(temp.U)*gamma[2]*k)/(exp(gamma[1]*temp.Z))))

    temp.C = rexp(1, 0.5)
    temp.obs = min(temp.T,temp.C)
    
    ## Append empty list
    failure = append(failure, temp.T); censor = append(censor,temp.C)
    obs = append(obs,temp.obs); ind = append(ind, 1*(temp.T==temp.obs))
    time_invariant = append(time_invariant,temp.Z)
    time_variant = append(time_variant, k*temp.obs) 
}
```

After generating the simulated data, I applied the `coxph` function treating the variable `time_invariant` as a time-invariant covariate and I estimate the `gamma[1]` parameter correctly.

```
mod = coxph(Surv(obs, ind) ~ time_invariant)
summary(mod)
```

I want to include the time-varying covariate `time_variant` into the coxph function to obtain an estimate of `gamma[2]`. How do I code the variable $Z(t)$ so that I can include it as a time-dependent covariate in the `coxph` function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) on time-dependence in survival models? See Section 5 on "Predictable time-dependent covariates," which seems to be what you need for a time-varying covariate like your Z(t).

Comment: I have tried using the tt code but the estimates do not match with the simulation parameters. My question is how to setup the code to include a time-varying covariate of the form $Z(t) = kt$. The code I used was

 mod = coxph(Surv(obs, ind)~time_invariant + tt(time_variant), tt = function(x, t, ...) {time_variant <- x*t})

summary(mod)

The estimates that were determined were:  4.442e-02 (time_invariant) and -1.887e+01 (time_variant)

Comment: Have you tried expanding the data set yourself to use the counting process format `Surv(startTime, stopTime, event)` instead of relying on the `tt()` function? As discussed in the vignette, that also allows for more extensive post-processing of the model fit.

Comment: I have tried to include longitudinal measurements for the time-dependent covariate and included them in the "start", "stop", "event" format but the coxph functions runs into numerical errors. I have essentially the same problem as [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313292/cox-survival-data-with-time-varying-continuous-variable-and-time-fixed-covariate?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the question of how to include the $Z(t)$ function into the coxph function was not resolved.

Comment: If $Z(t)$ is deterministic, i.e. does not change for different observations, then it's just part  of the baseline hazard. Same as a constant covariate  is just part of the intercept in a OLS

Answer (score 0):

First of, the baseline hazard is not really distributed, but an arbitrary function from time to $[0, \infty)$. A Cox-Model with one time invariant covariable $x_1$ and a time variant $x_2$ can be setup with a hazard function like this:
$$
\lambda(t, x_1, x_2) = \lambda_0(t) \cdot \exp(\gamma_1x_1 + \gamma_2f(t, x_2))
$$

$\lambda_0(t)$ being the baseline hazard. From here you could find the inverse CDF of the failure times for the case specific values of $x_{1/2}$ and then use that to sample failure times efficiently or just use your CPU and simulate with tiny time-steps $\Delta$ and with probability of failure $\Delta\lambda(t, x_1, x_2)$. I have made a few choices in my model to demonstrate the algorithm better, the big one being $f(t, x_2) = \sin(2\pi t)\cdot x_2$

```r
library(parallel)
library(survival)

gamma <- c(0.25, 0.5) # i want them a bit larger
base_hazard <- function(t){1}
loc_lambda <- function(t, x1, x2){
  base_hazard(t) * exp(gamma[1]*x1 + gamma[2] * sin(t*pi*2) * x2)
}

step_size <- 1/10^5 # very small 0.01 would be perfectly sufficient
sim_case <- function(x1, x2){
  failure <- FALSE
  t <- 0
  while(!failure){
    t <- t + step_size
    lambda_t <- loc_lambda(t, x1, x2)*step_size
    failure <- sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), size = 1, prob = c(1-lambda_t, lambda_t))
  }
  return(t)
}
sim_case(2, 3)

# setup data, n = 200 is too small for checking the algorithm
n <- 2000

dat <- data.frame(x1 = runif(n), x2 = runif(n))

# simulate with all but 2 of your CPU cores. takes about 1 minute on my machine(AMD Ryzen 5 3600)
start_time <- Sys.time()
print(start_time)
failure_times <- mcmapply(1:n, mc.cores = detectCores() - 2, FUN = function(i){
  sim_case(dat[i, "x1"], dat[i, "x2"])
})
print(Sys.time() - start_time)

censor_times <- rexp(n, 2)
dat$failure <- failure_times < censor_times
dat$time <- pmin(failure_times, censor_times)
summary(dat)
# follow the vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf
vfit3 <- coxph(Surv(time, failure) ~ x1 + tt(x2),
               data=dat,
               tt = function(x, t, ...) x * sin(t*pi*2))

summary(vfit3)
```

We recover the parameter values of $0.25, 0.5$ reasonably well:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, failure) ~ x1 + tt(x2), data = dat, 
    tt = function(x, t, ...) x * sin(t * pi * 2))

  n= 2000, number of events= 779 

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
x1     0.1576    1.1707   0.1237 1.274  0.20271   
tt(x2) 0.4785    1.6137   0.1808 2.646  0.00814 **
```

Now your question seems to imply, that you don't actually have a time variant covariate, but instead a feature that increases the hazard equally for all cases. This would be part of the baseline hazard and Cox-models explicitly try to avoid modeling the baseline hazard. I would point you towards Discrete-Time Survival, where the baseline hazard is model and can be tested:
https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/discrete-time-survival/